# How to add a function when deactivating Switch Button on ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uiswitch

I manage to add a function to Switch button on my component like so :

```
            <Switch
                onValueChange={(value)=>this.onPressIcon(_key)}
                style={{marginBottom: 10}}
                value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn}
            />
```

It triggers the function onPressIcon which increments a value by 1. 
Now, how can it triggers another function when the Switch button is deactivated ? (so the value will decrement)

Comment: You should have an intermediary function that references the 2 functions based on the state of the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `value` will return `true` when the switch is active and `false` otherwise. So you can use that to fire two different functions depending on the value. So something like the following:

```js
onPressIcon = (value) => {
  // if the switch is activated, execute increment function
  if (value) {
    this.incrementSomething();

    // ... rest of code

  } else {
    // switch is deactivated, execute other function
    this.otherFunction();

    // ... rest of code

  }
}

// render 
render () {
  return(

    //... rest of code

    <Switch
      onValueChange={(value) => this.onPressIcon(value)}
      style={{marginBottom: 10}}
      value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: @Sonia it's as easy as clicking the check mark beside my answer :)